# Devise Registrations controller rejecting POST from iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, devise

I am trying to make an RoR backend for an iOS app. I have decided to try and secure the API using Devise (3.2.4). However, I am unable to register a user via `http://localhost:3000/users` as generated by devise.

I have tried using both the default devise Registrations controller as well as overriding it and creating my own.

Using restkit, my iOS app is sending this JSON:

```
{"user":{"email":"Flash.gordon@gmail.com", "password":"Test123", "password_confirmation":"Test123"}}
```

## Method 1 - Standard Devise controller

Response is a 401 Unauthorized - `HTTP Token: Access denied.`

```
Started POST "/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-24 18:19:34 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"Flash.gordon@gmail.com"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"Flash.gordon@gmail.com"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  Rendered text template (0.1ms)
Filter chain halted as :restrict_access_by_token rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here, it seems that `:restrict_access_by_token` is being called. However, I'm not sure why as this is a post to register a new user, so I have no token to send, but am expecting one back. Also, I don't know why it doubles the parameters sent and adds a duplicate `registration` JSON array here.

## Method 2 - Overriding Devise Registrations Controller

After the above error, I tried ignoring ':restrict_access_by_token' for the 'create' method and updated routes accordingly

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "api/registrations"}
```

app/controllers/api/registrations_controller.rb

```
module API
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only => :create

  skip_before_filter :restrict_access_by_token, :only => :create
  respond_to :json


  def create
    user = User.new(sign_up_params)
    if user.save
      render :json=> user, :status=>201
      return
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render :json=> user.errors, :status=>422
    end
  end
end 
end
```

Response here is a `422 Unprocessable Entity` and the response is :

```
{"email":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank"]}
```

Server log:

```
Started POST "/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-24 18:30:08 -0400
Processing by API::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"Flash.gordon@gmail.com"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"Flash.gordon@gmail.com"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'flash.gordon@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 93ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Thus it seems that somehow, Devise is getting params and then not processing them correctly. Perhaps to do with the second `registration` JSON array.

Any ideas on how to fix these problems? should I ditch the custom controller? How do I get rid of the `registration` JSON array that it seems Devise is making?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to get around my problem. For Method 2 above (using my custom Registrations controller) I was getting the error response:

```
{"email":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank"]}
```

This was because I was sending the `password_confirmation` attribute as well, which is not needed for user registrations (only account updates I believe). After removing that, the JSON was parsed correctly by Devise.

For anyone having similar trouble with a Devise API, [I found this gist](https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6) helpful. There's a simple project here that I also used to model my JSON API to get around the deprecation of `:token_authenticatable` that is posted in [this repo by brianweiner.](https://github.com/brianweiner/basic_devise_json_api)

The only change I had to make was in the `user.rb` model. The last line of the loop `generate_authentication_token` should read as follows to avoid a noMethodError (based on the gist mentioned above):

```
      break token unless User.where(authentication_token: token).first
```